# Network computers go missing after a while

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have my home network set up with a streaming server (with network shared hdds) and 2 laptops running win7 and 8.1 respectively. Lately my win7 laptop has been experiencing disconnections from the "intranet", for lack of better words. It can access the internet just fine, but unable to remote connect to the server or access the network shares, or even the other laptop. This gets fixed every time I restart the win7, but occurs again within a half hour. I do not believe it is a server/router issue as the win8 laptop has had no issues accessing the drive while this is occurring. By my best guess, this has been happening since a windows update session a week or so ago.

Are there any steps I can take to diagnose the source of the problem, and fix it?

EDIT: The disconnection is not so much complete. While remote connections do not establish immediately, if I keep at it, it will eventually connect, but even then, once I disconnect, reconnecting will take multiple tries. Same with the hard drives. As long as they are in use, they remain connected, but once the read has stopped, accessing them again is a crapshoot.

Comment: Is your computer going to sleep?  Have you checked your various power settings?

Comment: Yes. The server is set to never sleep, and like I said, access from other devices works without a hitch. The laptop also doesn't go into sleep, and furthermore, the issue can happen even as I am actively using the laptop.

Comment: Is the server set to be Master Browser? Home networks fight over who should be in charge. You can set one machine to always 'win the election' [changing to Answer…]

Answer (score 0):

Is the server set to be Master Browser?

Home networks fight over who should be in charge.
You can set one machine to always 'win the election'

The Master Browser election setting is in the registry:

```
HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/Browser/Parameters/MaintainServerList
```

By default, all machines will be set to Auto.
Add the value `IsMasterBrowser` and set it to 1 to make that machine a master browser.

Comment: Yes, I added that tag when I was setting it up.

Comment: Same problem here. Setting IsMasterBrowser to 1 on server registry does nothing. I've had this random problem since Windows 7 - drives me nuts, all identical machines (literally) in a domain set up, but different machines show some, but not all PCs - head scratcher! I wish there was a real solution to this problem (now in Win 10!)